# How to append a variable in multiple netcdf files using ncatted?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, nco

I am trying to append the same attribute ("standard_name") to the variable latitude in **multiple** `netcdf` files.

```
ncatted -h -a standard_name,latitude,o,c,latitude agu028.nc
```

I want to make a loop in bash to filter through these files and make the necessary changes. I am using `ncatted` from NCO, but am new to `bash` scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for fl in `ls *.nc` ; do
  ncatted -h -a standard_name,latitude,o,c,latitude ${fl}
done
```

Comment: To make your answer useful, you should post an explanation of what it does and not only some code.

Comment: Thanks @Charlie Zender. Just what I was looking for!